# Eclipse hot key issues

Tags: eclipse, hotkeys

Okay, in Eclipse the the hotkey to run a Java Application is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.

When I hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, this menu comes up, with a bunch of commands with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, `insertCharHere`

I have no clue how to proceed run the Java application (with keys only, no mouse).

Answer (score 1):

The hotkey is actually <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>**,** <kbd>J</kbd>. *Note the comma.*

Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>and <kbd>Shift</kbd>, tap <kbd>X</kbd>, then release *all* keys and tap <kbd>J</kbd>.